# urllib and proxies

Tags: python, proxy, header, urllib

I need in using Tor+Privoxy with my python-script.

```
proxies = {
    'http'  : '127.0.0.1:8118',
    'ssl'   : '127.0.0.1:8118',
    'socks' : '127.0.0.1:9050'
}
```

The first question: is the '**socks**' name right? Maybe there should be something like '**socks5**'?
The next step is that I should pass user-agent string with this proxies to the urllib and save information from loaded site into .html file. I don't know how to pass headers information with proxies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use urllib2 instead. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079/how-to-specify-an-authenticated-proxy-for-a-python-http-connection) might be useful.
hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

not sure whether urllib is able to deal with socks proxy..
you may try [socksipy](http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/)