# Unable to login to a website using python script as I am behind a proxy which needs authentication

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I am using the following code to login to facebook .

```
import http.cookiejar
import urllib


url = 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php'
values = {'email' : 'john@example.com',
      'pass' : 'mypassword' }

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
cookies =  http.cookiejar.CookieJar()

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(
urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
urllib.request.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),
urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0),
urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies))

binary_data = data.encode('ascii')
response = opener.open(url, binary_data)
the_page = response.read()
http_headers = response.info()
```

But when I am behind a corporate Proxy firewall , The request always time out . 
Can You please get me a solution to authenticate through the proxy so that the request reached the remote facebook server .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763028/python-3-urllib-http-error-407-proxy-authentication-required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a proxy handler:

```
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(
    urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http': r'http://username:password@url:port'}),
    urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
    urllib.request.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),
    urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0),
    urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies)
)
```

Comment: Thank You for the reply .How do I get the proxy server url ? Also I am unable to ping www.google.com from command prompt . Is this because of the firewall ?

Comment: So, you don't have credentials for this proxy server?

Comment: I do have .. Its actually my corporate mailId/pass .

Comment: Check your web browser configuration - proxy address and port might be there

Comment: ICMP packets (ping) may be dropped by your firewall and you won't fix this if you are not the admin of this proxy server.

Comment: Hey , actually I do have an Automatic Proxy Configuration url . So how do I include the APC url in the above script ?

Comment: For APC the version without parameters should work http://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#proxies but you will have another problem with https - solution is here http://code.activestate.com/recipes/456195/