# Proxy detection in Python3

Tags: python, proxy

The script below works fine when I am using script at home (same PC!):

```
import urllib.request

x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com/')
print(x.read())
```

the same does not work using the same script when I am connected at work. I do not know proxy address or IP, so my script should use the same way as IE or anything else on this PC.

I found some suggestions about using proxy , but the point it I do not know proxy IP or details. When I move the script to another PC it might have different proxy, so I think hardcoding it is not good approach.
Can I somehow inform Python to autodetect proxy settings?

Comment: `does not work` phrase is very vague and open to interpretation. Giving error details might unblock you, rather than going to a solution related to `autodetect proxy settings`?

Comment: ok. fair point. When I execute it from company network I get this: urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond> . When I excute the same from home - everything works fine, so the question is how to properly inform Python to autodetect local proxy settings.The page which I try to open is no blocked (I am sure about it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Going by your eample, I am assuming you are doing a `https` call over proxy. The `urllib` documentation hints [its not supported](https://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/urllib2.html#proxies). So, instead you may have to settle down with `http`.
2. In order to validate that there is nothing wrong with your setup, you may try to do open the IP directly:

```
    import urllib
    # IP address for `http://www.google.com` is `216.58.205.196`
    x = urllib.urlopen('http://216.58.205.196')
    print x.read()
```

3. A. There are lots of complaints about Python's trippy auto-detect proxy settings in various other threads. I had this issue only once years ago and I opted for setting a fixed proxy instead of trying to configure `auto-detect`. To know your proxy, you can go to chrome url `chrome://net-internals/#proxy` or run `netstat -an | grep EST` command.

   B. Once you have proxy address, you can use following code:

```
    import urllib
    # IP address for `http://www.google.com` is `216.58.205.196`
    x = urllib.urlopen('http://216.58.205.196', 
                        proxies={'http': 'http://www.someproxy.com:3128'})
    print x.read()
```

4. If you cannot avoid `https`, then you may consider `requests` library. I didn't test this, but [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies) looks quite promising. This is how it can be done!

```
    import requests
    proxies = {
      'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
      'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
    }
    requests.get('https://example.org', proxies=proxies)
```

Edit:

1: You may need to setup [proxy authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11763340/3991696) in order for `3.B.` to work

2: For Special characters, you would need to have the password in unicode: `'p@ssw0rd'.decode('utf-8')`

Hope this helps!

Comment: in the meantime I manged to move one step forward with this script and get error: raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authentication Required. I think I know whats next step. thanks for advice

Comment: You would be using some `authentication` for your proxy, and because this script does not provide any, it would obviously fail. Added it in the answer, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: thanks. What shall I do in the case my password contains '@' as a special character? This is real case. My real password has this special character. if I need to use something like this: http://username:pass@word@url:port, then how Python knows which '@' is end of the password? Anyway. I want to user Python to grab some data from one of cloud solutions we use. Data are in JSON, but all runs with https. I also found information that HTTPS is not supported, so what is other option?

Comment: For special characters in password, you would need to convert into unicode.

Comment: I think, you may go with `requests` library then. Added in the answer though not tested it!

Comment: that's what I did and now all works fine. thanks a lot for help. At my company I also needed to provide logon details to go via PROXY, but now I get what I want.