# 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: python, django, windows

I'm trying to use django-social-auth in my django app. While everything is ok on my mac, I got  407 Proxy Authentication Required when I'm trying to use same code on windows machine.

```
 <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront 

TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your local proxy configuration.

Answer (score 2):

```
Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request
```

It looks like your machine is configured (required?) to route outbound traffic through a proxy server (Microsoft's TMG, in this case). When a user tries to authenticate with your app, Django is trying to connect to another service to verify them, but it can't reach that service, because of the proxy configuration.

Since the code that calls `urlopen` is probably within django-social-auth, you may not want to modify that directly to use the proxy. You can try setting an `http_proxy` environment variable (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3942980/70605) for details) to make *all* urllib requests go through the proxy), or disable proxy authentication for your web server.