# Visual Studio build - "(407) Proxy Authentication Required" when build xamarin Droid project

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, build, proxy-authentication

I used network proxy which needs username/password for authentication in our company.
I am working on Xamarin development, and using visual studio 2015 as IDE.
When I build Android project, many errors occurred. The main error is "(407) Proxy Authentication Required".

I tried to edit devenv.exe.config, but it is useless.

### I tried this suggestions, all are useless.

[Package manager in Visual Studio 2015 "407 (Proxy Authentication Required)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310915/package-manager-in-visual-studio-2015-407-proxy-authentication-required)

### [407 Proxy Authentication Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203211/407-proxy-authentication-required)

How can I solve this issue? Any help?

---

Severity Code Description Project File Line Source Suppression State
Error Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist. App1.Droid Build
Error Reason: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required. App1.Droid Build
Error Reason: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required. App1.Droid Build
Error Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\content./ doesn't exist. App1.Droid Build
Error Download failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and put it to the C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0 directory. App1.Droid Build
Error Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist. App1.Droid Build
Error Reason: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required. App1.Droid Build

### Error Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\23.3.0.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist. App1.Droid Build

Thanks,
Airong

Comment: The build process is trying to download/cache packages from google. It needs access to `https://dl-ssl.google.com`... The error msg contains the link and directory location if you need to manually download them: i.e. `Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and put it to the C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0 directory.`

Comment: Please review this document I wrote on the topic: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/

Comment: Thanks, I tried these steps from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418129/xamarin-forms-android-project-build-error-missing-files-inside-appdata-local?rq=1, it works. 
1.download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip

2.rename to 2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip

3.copy to C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips

4.rebuild

Comment: Thanks @JonDouglas your article has helped me in the past with similar issues. However is there still no way to provide credentials in visual studio for the proxy?