# Using a Python script to establish FTP connection behind FTP proxy

Tags: python, proxy, ftp, urllib2, ftplib

Im trying to connect to an ftp server that is behind ftp proxy. 
The proxy server does not require username and password, the ftp server does.
I have searched through several posts:

[Proxies in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293518/proxies-in-python-ftp-application)

[How to use urllib2 to access ftp/http server using proxy with authentification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925098/how-to-use-urllib2-to-access-ftp-http-server-using-proxy-with-authentification)

[How to connect to ftp server via proxy using ftplib](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2004-October/249389.html)

[How to specify an authenticated proxy for a python http connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079/how-to-specify-an-authenticated-proxy-for-a-python-http-connection)

Here is the last version of my code. So far I've figured out that to open the ftp server behind an ftp proxy, the notation `ftp://username:password@server` can be used. I'm using the urllib2 library to define the proxy server.

```
import urllib2

proxy_host = '101.11.44.84:8021'  # only host name, no scheme (http/ftp)
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'ftp': proxy_host}) 
auth = urllib2.FTPHandler()
try:
    opener_thru_proxy = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler, auth)
except:
    logger.exception('build_opener error')    
    raise
print opener_thru_proxy
try:
    conn = opener_thru_proxy.open('ftp://user:password@100.159.66.113')
except:
    logger.exception('opener thru proxy error')
    raise
print conn.read()
conn.close()
```

The output of this code yields:

```
2016-05-23 16:15:28,286 - root - ERROR - opener thru proxy error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 293, in <module>
  File "C:\_Studna\Python\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
  File "C:\_Studna\Python\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
  File "C:\_Studna\Python\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
  File "C:\_Studna\Python\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\urllib2.py", line 1412, in ftp_open
  File "C:\_Studna\Python\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\urllib2.py", line 1434, in connect_ftp
  File "C:\_Studna\Python\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\urllib.py", line 875, in __init__
  File "C:\_Studna\Python\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\urllib.py", line 884, in init
  File "C:\_Studna\Python\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\ftplib.py", line 135, in connect
  File "C:\_Studna\Python\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
URLError: <urlopen error ftp error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

It seems that I'm unable to establish the ftp connection with the ftp server.
However, when I use the same set of connection data and use it in Total Commander, the connection works correctly. See the image enclosed [Total Commander ftp connection window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMoq1.jpg).

Comment: I have managed to connect to the ftp server behind ftp proxy using [Winscp](https://winscp.net/).  When I use the connection string  `open ftp://login:pwd@server:port -passive=on -rawsettings FtpProxyLogonType=2 ProxyHost=proxyaddress ProxyPort=proxyport ProxyUsername=user`. Can I somehow enter the same parameters when setting up an ftp connection in Python?