# What's the format for urllib2 request proxies?

Tags: python, urllib2

According to the documentation, this is the format:

```
Request.set_proxy(host, type)
```

So what I have is this for example:

```
Request.set_proxy("localhost:8888","http")
```

What is the format if the proxy requires a username and password?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079/how-to-specify-an-authenticated-proxy-for-a-python-http-connection)

Comment: Lol no it's not. That's using an opener. I want to use it on the request object like I've shown above.

Comment: Laugh away... but you can't do it directly via Request's public interface, but you can manually set the Proxy-Authorization header - see answer below. Generally, you are better of using the "opener" approach, or even better to use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies) library - if your requirements permit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do this if you must use a urllib2.Request object:

Set environment variables `http_proxy` and/or `https_proxy` either outside of the Python interpreter, or internally using `os.environ['http_proxy']` before you import `urllib2`.

```
import os
os.environ['http_proxy'] = 'http://user:password@localhost:8888'
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.blah.com')
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Or manually set HTTP request header:

```
import urllib2
from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode
PROXY_USERNAME = 'user'
PROXY_PASSWORD = 'password'
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.blah.com')
req.set_proxy('localhost:8888', 'http')
proxy_auth = urlsafe_b64encode('%s:%s' % (PROXY_USERNAME, PROXY_PASSWORD))
req.add_header('Proxy-Authorization', 'Basic %s' % proxy_auth)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```