# How to access webpages using Python via a proxy

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am writing a small program to fetch all hyperlinks from a webpage by providing a URL, but it seem like the network I am in is using proxy and it is not able to fetch ..
My code:

```
import sys
import urllib
import urlparse

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def process(url):
    page = urllib.urlopen(url) 
    text = page.read()
    page.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text) 
    with open('s.txt','w') as file:
        for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
            tag['href'] = urlparse.urljoin(url, tag['href'])
            print tag['href']
            file.write('\n')
            file.write(tag['href'])


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print 'No url !!'
        sys.exit(1)
    for url in sys.argv[1:]:
        process(url)
```

Comment: Based on your question your network may or may not have a proxy in use. Can you be a little more specific or just pass by your admins and ask?

Comment: yes , it have a proxy ,i tried at home it was working fine but when i took it to my Department to show to my teacher it dint work ...this is the error
`IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

Comment: this is the proxy i used too connect "proxy4.nehu.ac.in:3128" how do i put it in codes in my program ..? please help , i am so stuck with it .

Comment: ok i will check on this and i will come back to you if i encounter some problem ..at this moment i cannot test it because i have to try it at the University itself since i dont have proxy network to test . If it ok with you?

Comment: you can easily set up a proxy on your own. E.g. squid is quiet popular.

Comment: OK i dint know ...thanks i will surely take a look ..thanks for you time ..cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the requests module instead.

```py
import requests

proxies = { 'http': 'http://host/' } 
# or if it requires authentication 'http://user:pass@host/' instead

r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
text = r.text
```

Comment: should i put it this way
`proxies = { 'http': 'http://proxya4.nehu.ac.in }`

Comment: You need the port and closing quote. So it would be `proxies = { 'http': 'http://proxya4.nehu.ac.in:3128' }`

Comment: Can i come back to you later i will try first an let u know how it goes?..i really want this to work ..im like crying inside so bad.

Comment: Hi, i tried your suggestion i got 'response 200' when i print `r=requests.get("http://www.dota2.com",proxies=poxies)` what does it means.

Comment: 200 is the status code for the response. It is saying the response was ok. [1] To get the html from the page, you need to print `r.text`.
[1]: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Its working Thanks alot ...sorry for late reply

Comment: I thought this was working for me, but tried putting random information passed in with proxies and data was still retrieved each time (as long as https was used).

Answer (score 1):

The `urllib` library you are using for HTTP access does not support proxy authentication (it does support un-authenticated proxies). From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html):

> Proxies which require authentication for use are not currently
>   supported; this is considered an implementation limitation.

I suggest you switch to `urllib2` and use it as demonstrated in [the answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079/how-to-specify-an-authenticated-proxy-for-a-python-http-connection).

Comment: I am new to python so its hard for me to implement , just for the head start can u like somehow show me how should i put it in my program ..?

Comment: i have read in the python documentation that there is a proxyHandler in urllib2 that can handle proxy , how to i put it in such a way that it will go through the proxy i used to connect to the internet.Please help