# How to perform HTTPS post in python using proxy credentials

Tags: python, proxy

h = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host,port, timeout=15)

h.request('POST', url, data, headers)

r = h.getresponse()

Normally, I perform https post in python like given above. Now if I have a proxy server's username and password how can I perform https post using that proxy crendentials.

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079/how-to-specify-an-authenticated-proxy-for-a-python-http-connection

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36259667/https-post-using-proxy-in-python                                                                                                                  I tried the code in this link will this work