# HTTPS Post using proxy in python

Tags: python, proxy

```
http_proxy_full_auth_string = "https://%s:%s@%s:%s" % (http_proxy_user,http_proxy_passwd,http_proxy_server,http_proxy_port)

proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"https":http_proxy_full_auth_string})

proxy_auth_handler = urllib2.ProxyBasicAuthHandler()

proxy_auth_handler.add_password(None, 'host','user', 'passwd')

opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler,proxy_auth_handler)

urllib2.install_opener(opener)

urllib2.urlopen(uri)

request=urllib2.Request(url,data,headers)

request.get_method = lambda: 'POST'

r = opener.open(request)
```

This is my code to perform https post in python using proxy. Will this work. I am getting r.code as 200, but the data is not received on the other side.

Comment: I would recommend using http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies although  your code looks correct

Comment: Thank you. This will help, but i want to know why data is not received on the other end by using my python code. On the other side i use java                                                                                            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();   reader.readLine();            but readline is null even when if i mention data in my code.